# Indexing mongoose timestamps

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema like so:

```
let PictureSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  ...
}, {timestamps: true})

PictureSchema.index({"createdAt": 1});
PictureSchema.index({"updatedAt": 1});
```

I'm trying to get the fields "*createdAt*" and "*updatedAt*" indexed. When using

```
PictureSchema.index({"createdAt": 1});
PictureSchema.index({"updatedAt": 1});
```

It doesn't work and all other indexes except "_id_" also stop working.

I got a variation of this working by using the mongoose-timestamp plugin like so:

```
PictureSchema.plugin(timestamps, {
  createdAt: {
    name: 'createdAt',
    type: Date,
    index: true
  },
  updatedAt: {
    name: 'updatedAt',
    type: Date,
    index: true
  }
})
```

But the problem I have with this plugin is that it doesn't record UTC time but system time. A fix to my problem would also be to get mongoose-timestamp to record UTC time but preferably I would prefer to index the fields provided by the built in timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out

```
 PictureSchema.index({"createdAt": 1});
 PictureSchema.index({"updatedAt": 1});
```

Works perfectly. Had to restart the database server a couple of times to get it working.

Wondering why is that?